# angular2 plain javascript indexeddb connection

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular 2. Already I have done mobile application in angularjs, compared to angularjs angular 2 tags are different. I tried to access ngModel inside the indexed method, but it is not working.

Comment: Show your code thats not working please